# PlugIn for Update or Create Node in xml Webresource in CRM 2011

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I want PlugIn that can create or update node in xml web Resource in CRM 2011..

For Example I have Webresource of XML File like this Thus is Parent-Child Node in xml file...

```
<root name="account">
<node cId="6343cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" cName="Blue Company (sample)" pId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" pName="">
<node cId="5f43cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" cName="Best o' Things (sample)" pId="6343cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" pName="Blue Company (sample)" />
```

```
<node cId="6543cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" cName="Elemental Goods (sample)" pId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" pName="" />
<node cId="6743cd70-cd0e-e211-b10a-984be173a3b0" cName="Grand Store (sample)" pId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" pName="" />
 </root>
```

Now i want such a PlugIn that can update or create node on the basis of Parent-Child Account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this link](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/03/editing-embedded-web-resource-contents.html) you have example of editing HTML web resource. You can use the same way for XML ws.

*Adding new node:* Load your xml in, for example, XDocument doc and add new node:

```
var newElement = new XElement("node");
newElement.SetAttributeValue("cId", "123456");
newElement.SetAttributeValue("cName", "Test cName");
newElement.SetAttributeValue("pId", "321564");
newElement.SetAttributeValue("pName", "Test pName");

doc.Root.Add(newElement);
```

After just update your web resource content.

Hope it helps :)